# How to Copy Worksheet to an Existing Sheet with gspread?

Tags: python, gspread

In Google Sheets one is able to manually copy a worksheet in a given sheet to another sheet; I want to do this programmatically with `gspread`. For example, if I have 2 sheets in my drive--*spreadsheet_1* and *spreadsheet_2*--I want to copy worksheet *ws_1* from *spreadsheet_1* to *spreadsheet_2*.

I read through some of the [gspread documentation](https://docs.gspread.org/en/v5.10.0/api/models/worksheet.html#gspread.worksheet.Worksheet.copy_to) and found that the `Worksheet` object has a method called `copy_to` that copies a given worksheet to another sheet. I tried using it in the following code.

```
# import, authenticate, make gspread client
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()

import gspread
from google.auth import default

creds, _ = default()
gc = gspread.authorize(creds)

# access worksheet ws_1 from sheet spreadsheet_1
sh_1 = gc.open('spreadsheet_1')
ws = sh_1.worksheet('ws_1')

# copy the worksheet to spreadsheet_2
sh_2 = gc.open('spreadsheet_2')
ws.copy_to(sh_2.id) # reference spreadsheet_2 with its id
```

Error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-b388ead7ce3a> in <cell line: 5>()
      3 
      4 sh_2 = gc.open('spreadsheet_2')
----> 5 ws.copy_to(sh_2.id)

AttributeError: 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'copy_to'
```

But as per the attribute error I received, `Worksheet` doesn't actually have such a method. I tried looking further in to the docs but its really not clear how this task can be accomplished.

Comment: In your showing script, I think that `ws = sh.worksheet('ws_1')` is required to be modified to `ws = sh_1.worksheet('ws_1')`. How about this? But, I'm not sure whether this is related to your current issue. I apologize.

Comment: I missed it while changing the variable names for the post, but its not related to the issue. Thanks for the pointing it out though!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I understood it. By the way, what version of gspread are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 3.4.2

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `I'm using version 3.4.2`, in the current stage, it seems that the current version is v5.11.1. [Ref](https://github.com/burnash/gspread/releases/tag/v5.11.1) So, can you test your showing script with the latest version? I'm worried that the reason for your current issue might be due to the version of gspread.

Comment: Yeah, I think you're correct. I checked the [Release History](https://github.com/burnash/gspread/blob/master/HISTORY.rst#360-2020-04-30) on github and it says that ```Worksheet.copy_to``` was released in 3.6.0. I appreciate your help!

Comment: Thank you for replying. If your issue was resolved, how about posting it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Upgrade `gspread` Version to Use Worksheet.copy_to

Every Notebook in Google Colab comes with gspread 3.4.2 pre-installed.

- run `!pip list -v | grep gspread` in a cell to see the version and location

According to [Release History](https://github.com/burnash/gspread/blob/master/HISTORY.rst#360-2020-04-30) in the gpsread repository, version 3.6.0 saw the addition of `Worksheet.copy_to`. Thus one must update their version of gspread to use the method.

- Update to lastest version: `!pip install --upgrade gspread`
- Install specific version (e.g. 3.6.0): `!pip install gspread==3.6.0`

### Alternative to Upgrading

If for whatever reason one doesn't want to upgrade to a version that has the method, the following function can be used instead.

```
def copy_to(gs_client, sheet_id, spreadsheet_id, destination_spreadsheet_id):
    """
    Directly calls `spreadsheets.sheets.copyTo
    <https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.sheets/copyTo>`_.
    """

    url = f"https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheet_id}/sheets/{sheet_id}:copyTo"

    body = {"destinationSpreadsheetId": destination_spreadsheet_id}
    r = gs_client.request("post", url, json=body)
    return r.json()
```

This achieves the same end result as `Worksheet.copy_to`. This is basically how `Worksheet.copy_to` works; I took it from the module's [source code](https://github.com/burnash/gspread/blob/master/gspread/spreadsheet.py#L233).